# Fetching or Deleting Entity from Google App Engine DB with Unicode Property Name

Tags: google-app-engine, unicode, model

I have an Expando model kind in my App Engine datastore and I'm setting many arbitrary property names. I didn't consider that I couldn't store Unicode property names, and now I'm in a troubling situation where any attempt to fetch entities of this kind, or even deleting them to get rid of the offender get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/APP/1-05.335746938130078870/console/app/models/console.py", line 146, in processSource
    exec bytecode in statement_module.__dict__
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1461, in fetch
    return [self._model_class.from_entity(e) for e in raw]
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1047, in from_entity
    entity_values = cls._load_entity_values(entity)
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1347, in _load_entity_values
    entity_values[str(key)] = value
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Now I've changed my code to encode these property names to ascii in advance of saving them, but it's too late! Because there is at least one entity with a Unicode-typed property name, it is impossible for me to fetch the entity or delete it, and this means that the Datastore viewer is returning a "A server error has occurred." error, so I can't even see where the problem is.

The only think I can think of is forking the db module and change the str() method, but it would just be a lot easier for me to find a way to wipe this Model, or even better, to be able to delete the offending entity (or entities) without getting rid of all of the valid ones.

Comment: One way to do this may be to get the keys of all of these entities, and then do a try block to see if I can fetch each one, and when the exception is thrown delete the entity just by using the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment I left ended up working.

Here's the solution (assuming there are under 1000 of such entities):

```
entities = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM ExpandoModel").fetch(1000)

for e in entities:

  try: db.get(e)
  except UnicodeEncodeError: db.delete(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you can also import and use the google.appengine.api.datastore module, which provides a lower-level, dict-based interface to the datastore.

You might also want to [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) about this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've filed an issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2007